# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar la posicion de un personaje?

Tags: java

Tengo una clase principal donde se especifica el tablero. Hay 3 tipos limite (NO puede pasar) , vacio (tambien pasa el jugador) y casilla (donde el jugador puede pasar) . No creo que haga falta enseñaros el codigo que he realizado, ya que solamente hablo del tablero.

En la clase que os pregunto quiero realizar un método que a partir de la posición del jugador, el tablero y un movimiento(puede ser arriba, abajo...) actualice la posicion del jugador. Para ello, tengo creado esto en la clase:

//Posicion del tablero del jugador(es aleatorio no me he basado en una posicion determinada)

```
    int[] posicion = new int[2];

    posicion[0] = 1;
    posicion[1] = 4;

    return posicion;
}
```

//ACTUALIZAR LA POSICION DEL SUPERVIVIENTE . AQUÍ VIENE LA PREGUNTA QUE COMENTABA

```
public static int moverJugador(int[] posicionJugador, int[][] tablero, String movimiento) {
```

En el metodo que pongo, tengo que realizar las operaciones de mover y comprobar que no sea una posicion limite.

Comment: Hola! veo que ya formateas el codigo ^^ pero parece que tienes el metodo `moverPersonaje` incompleto ... puedes dar mas información? como es el escenario?

Comment: Con la poca información que nos has puesto es imposible darte una respuesta clara. ¿Cómo se mueve el personaje? ¿Usas la entrada de teclado? ¿Tienes algún sistema de coordenadas o el movimiento está establecido en unas posiciones discretas? ¿Es por turnos o en tiempo real? ¿Tienes implementado algo del game loop? etc... O pones toda esa información y más o localiza mejor dónde estás teniendo el problema para poder solucionar algo en concreto.

Comment: Hola, perdona si me he explicado mal. Las coordenadas que he puesto, son las coordenadas por donde tiene que ir el personaje. (esta en otra clase, no lo he puesto porque eso lo implementa bien)  El metodo que he puesto "moverPersonaje" tengo esos datos que tiene que devolver(posicionPersonaje, int[][] tablero, String movimiento) {
  posicion[x][y];) lo que hay que hacer es actualizar la posicion del personaje y  comprobar que no se sale del tablero que esta en la clase que he comentado anteriormente. Perdona, no he puesto la otra clase para que no tuvierais confusión. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Perdona pero sigo igual. Deberías de usar variables que dejaran más claro qué contienen. Si veo simplemente `int[]` no tengo ni idea de lo que contiene. Si veo `int x`, `int y` ya tengo algo más de idea. Por otra parte sigo sin saber cómo debería avanzar por esa posición ¿Una pulsación de teclado es sumar uno en un sentido? ¿Se tiene que mover hasta una posición sobre la que hago click? ¿Dónde esta el game loop para refrescar la pantalla y se vea el movimiento? Si no haces esto aunque te movieras no se vería, etc...

Comment: pero no expliques en los comentarios.. edita la pregunta para que quede todo lo completa que puedas..

Comment: Ya la he modificado @lois6b

Comment: Ya la he modificado @Awes0meM4n

Comment: A mi lo que no me queda claro es como situas exactamente con 1 dígito la posición en el tablero, imagino que el tablero es un cuadrado de, por poner un ejemplo, 8x8, si le pasas un 1 en la posicion 0 y un 4 en la posicion uno, interpreto que se mueve 1 casilla en el primer movimiento y 4 en el segundo, pero no se hacia donde. Tampoco tengo claro que indica el String movimiento (hacia donde se mueve ¿quizá?). Tal y como lo tienes lo que parece es que la posición del jugador ya se esté actualizando en la otra función

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas.

Probablemente esto resuelva tu problema:

```
public static void moverJugador(int[] posicionJugador, int[][] tablero, String movimiento) {
    int x = posicionJugador[0], y = posicionJugador[1];

    switch (movimiento) {
        case "arriba":
            if (comprobarMovimiento(x, y + 1, tablero))
                y++;
            break;
        case "abajo":
            if (comprobarMovimiento(x, y - 1, tablero))
                y--;
            break;
        case "derecha":
            if (comprobarMovimiento(x + 1, y, tablero))
                x++;
            break;
        case "izquierda":
            if (comprobarMovimiento(x - 1, y, tablero))
                x--;
            break;
    }

    posicionJugador[0] = x;
    posicionJugador[1] = y;
}

private static boolean comprobarMovimiento(int x, int y, int[][] tablero) {
    // restricciones sobre el tamaño del tablero
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || y > tablero.length || x > tablero[0].length)
        return false;

    // restricciones sobre el problema
    // 0 = tipo 1 (no puede pasar)
    // 1 = tipo 2
    // 2 = tipo 3
    if (tablero[y][x] == 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias!! voy a probarlo :)

Comment: Gracias, has solucionado mi problema :)